# WhatsApp API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, whatsapp

I want to use the whatsapp API in my rails app.

Is there any recommended guide or gem to implement WhatsApp APIs in ruby on rails?

Thanks.

Comment: did you found any solution regarding your question, give  me any hint?

Comment: You can try the whatsapi gem located here: https://github.com/ongair/whatsapi

Comment: Didn't even had an idea that there was a Whatsapp API! There wasn't one, and all the existing ones were disabled except for iphone after facebook bought them, I think

Comment: FYI: `whatsapi' gem is not supported nowadays, it's sad but it's true :(

Comment: Hey, you can use the newly released Cloud API. There are wrappers out there https://github.com/ignacio-chiazzo/whatsapp_sdk